# Trigger fire event after even after page load

Tags: jquery

Hi the code below successfully adds the function back to the `onclick` attribute in my html, (after being removed previously), but it does not fire again, as it would normally do after page load.

How can I make this fire again so that the function runs?

```
$jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $("#id").attr( "onclick", "doSomething();");
});
```

(FYI, I will soon be changing over to non-HTML `onclick` events, so I am already aware that my code could be done differently.)

Comment: "as it would normally do after page load"? Why? You're just adding a reference in the attribute, not firing it.

Comment: Yeah, I probably just don't understand exactly how it works, so it probably makes no sense...sorry.

Comment: @Johan, and I tried using `.on` as suggested below by @palash, but it does not allow my function to fire.  Not sure why

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you're trying to accomplish? Trigger the function on click + triggering it once manually on page load?

Comment: @Johan, I want to do this: 1) load the page, 2) remove the current `onclick` event, 3) re-add the `onclick` event with my code above. That is what I want to happen, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Johan, I'm removing the `onclick` to disable a button from being clicked

Comment: Why not disable it? `$("#id").prop({ disabled: true });`

Comment: @Johan, that's great! How do I enable the button again after I do this.  I will need that to happen.

Comment: Sorry, went afk. `disabled: false` :]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method like:

```
$jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id").on("click", doSomething);
});
```

Comment: @palash, so this function should fire normally even if triggered by a click later after page load right?  I've tried this and it didn't work previously.

Comment: @RobMyrick Try using event delegation: `$(document).on('click', '#id', doSomething);`

Comment: @RobMyrick Is the `#id` element added dynamically?